# Django PermissionRequiredMixin not working when user doesn't have the permission required

Tags: django, django-permissions

Okay i have this view and im using django PermissionRequiredMixin, when the user has the change_item permission i specify there all works fine

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin

class MyView(PermissionRequiredMixin,View):

    template = 'myapp/item_detail.html'
    permission_required = 'myapp.change_item'


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #Query here
        return render(request, self.template)
```

But,when user doesn't have it, i got a 404 error page saying that myapp/login it's not valid:

```
**Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/login?next=/myapp/item/35/**
The current URL, myapp/login, didn't match any of these.
```

That login it's set in settings LOGIN_URL and works perfectly with everything else...but not with this, and i also see that a login string it's in the middle of the url from the error...am i missing something about mixins ?, what am i doing wrong ??

I add the urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views.views_home import HomeView, WelcomeView
from .views.views_authentication import LoginView, LogoutView, ChangePasswordView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^welcome/$', WelcomeView.as_view(), name="welcome"),
    url(r'^home/$', HomeView.as_view(), name="home"),
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
    url(r'^logout/$', LogoutView, name="logout"),
    url(r'^change_password/$', ChangePasswordView.as_view(), name="change_password"),

]
```

And the stack trace:

```
[03/Oct/2016 17:04:47] "GET /myapp/item/35/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
Not Found: /myapp/login
[03/Oct/2016 17:04:47] "GET /myapp/login?next=/myapp/item/35/ HTTP/1.1" 404 32312
```

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

When using the PermissionRequiredMixin, you can use the [LOGIN_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-LOGIN_URL) in settings.py to redirect the user to the current page. if myapp/login/ isn't the correct location, please use this setting to specify the right one. Also instead of using settings.LOGIN_URL, you can add a `login_url` class member to your view or you can add a `get_login_url()` method.

All of these things assume that myapp/login isn't the correct location, if that's indeed where you want the user redirected to, that means you have an error in urls.py

Last but not least, when using DRF, it's customary to use [DjangoModelPermissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissions) instead of `PermissionRequiredMixin`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As i said before myapp/login it's the right location, it's set in settings.py and works perfectly with other redirections like login_required decorator...i don't know whatś wrong...

Comment: Sure @e4c5 i just added it

Comment: ALready got it, login url for  login_required decorator works with 'myapp/login', permissionrequiredmixin somehow needs '/myapp/login/'....i'll search why, thanks for your help !!